# barcode flutter scan doesn't get result mobile app

Tags: flutter, mobile, callback, barcode

I try to read barcode using flutter mobile, I using this function

```
 scanbarcode() async {
    await FlutterBarcodeScanner.scanBarcode(
        '#000000', 'Cancel', true, ScanMode.BARCODE)
        .then((value) => setState(() => text = value));
  }
```

it open camera and show scan line but it doesn't get the result it text, and when I press back or cancel it get me -1 in txt.
and that when I call

```
onPressed: () async {
                           await scanbarcode();
                        }
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know that on emultated phones bar and Qr code scanner do not work well so try to run your app on a real device. Otherwise I cannot help you more with your problem but I implemented a bar/QR code scanner few day ago with the `qr_code_scanner: ^1.0.0` package and it worked for me.

Hier is the link of the package: https://pub.dev/packages/qr_code_scanner

and here the code exemple:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final qrKey = GlobalKey(debugLabel: 'QR');
    QRViewController? controller;
    void onQRViewCreated(QRViewController controllerAt) {
      controller = controllerAt;
      controllerAt.pauseCamera();
      controller!.resumeCamera();
      controller!.scannedDataStream.listen((barcode) {
       
      // Hier you get the barcode or qr code if it's scanned

      });
    }

    Widget _getBarQrScannerWidget() {
      return QRView(
        key: qrKey,
        onQRViewCreated: onQRViewCreated,
        overlay: QrScannerOverlayShape(
          cutOutSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.75,
          borderWidth: 10,
          borderLength: 15,
          borderRadius: 8,
        ),
      );
    }
return getBarQrScannerWidget()
}
```